# Context Menu in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, controls, contextmenu, monodevelop

I have a button that when I click it, a context menu should appear. I know in Visual Studio there is a context menu control in the toolbox, but I don't see a context menu control in MonoDevelop's (version 2.6) toolbox.

Is there a way to import the context menu control into MonoDevelop? Or does the control even exist for MonoDevelop?

If there is really no context menu control for MonoDevelop then is there a way I can make a custom context menu? Or some other alternative would be fine.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the Mono GTK implementation of [menu](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3aGtk.Menu) for this type of thing. Seems to work pretty well.